# Multi-class classification metrics in R and Python

Tags: python, r, multiclass-classification

I would like to ask if there is a metric in R and Python that serves not only for binary classification. I've found Matthews Correlation Coefficient works well in Python, but in R is only a binary version. Of course, I'm talking about "real" not just binary metrics - not something like "It's binary, but you can use one vs one or one vs all."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this? [MLR's performance measures](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/performance/index.html)

Performance measure suitable for the iris classification task
listMeasures(iris.task)

> 1] "kappa"            "multiclass.brier" "multiclass.aunp" 
>    [4] "multiclass.aunu"  "qsr"              "ber"
>    [7] "logloss"          "wkappa"           "timeboth"
>   [10] "timepredict"      "acc"              "lsr"
>   [13] "featperc"         "multiclass.au1p"  "multiclass.au1u" 
>   [16] "ssr"              "timetrain"        "mmce"

[Caret does too but fewer](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html).

Comment: I asked for the multi-class classification and not the multi label classification.

Comment: Please do not change your post when someone has already written an answer.
Going to the bottom, the cohen kappa score is what I needed. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

How about the `MLmetrics` package in R? It has multi class log loss function that you can use to assess the performance of your model.

Comment: This solution is good. But I'm looking for something where inputs would be just categories not probability matrices.